# Flickering of text area in firefox with height = inherit. What could be the reason for this?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, windows, firefox

I am facing an issue with Firefox on Windows. It works fine on MAC and Ubuntu. To describe the issue, I recorded a small video (7 seconds) and put it [here on youtube](https://youtu.be/KBQzXAuCzLM) (so that it helps)

The issue is that the text area keeps on flickering, growing, and reducing its size, infinitely.

```
.editable-area {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  textarea {
    resize: none;
    max-height: inherit;
    min-height: inherit;
    height: inherit !important;
 }
}
```

It happens because of the property `height: inherit !important` on node `textarea`. If I remove `height: inherit` and just make it `40px` or simply remove it, there is no flickering but yes, then the height is not as that of its parent. I am using [antd's editable paragraph](https://codesandbox.io/s/eeqk3) and using it as follows:

```
 <div>
            <Paragraph
                key={props.targetStringId}
                className={"font-weight-normal editable-area mb-0"}
                editable={{
                    editing,
                }}
            >
                {currentVal}
            </Paragraph>
 </div>
```

As you could see `editable-area` class is added to `Paragraph` component.

Could someone, please suggest what could be the issue? I am sorry if I could not post more details as this is something, I could not understand. Please let me know if I can add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time inspecting the behavior, I found out it was due to missing `height` property in the parent element. Since the parent had a missing `height` attribute, the child element with `height: inherit` gave an undefined behavior.

I tried giving the parent element a height (in my case, I gave it `100%`) and the flickering went away.